# Elementary OS 6 font seems to be with low resolution

Tags: display, resolution, fonts

I don't quite understand the reason for the problem, but apparently the font was more "beautiful" in Elementary OS 5. Now it looks like a font when you select a wrong monitor resolution (but the resolution is the same).

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There is a discussion on Reddit about that. It seems that on some displays the font looks ugly but apparently not on all displays and not all font types.
I've noticed this problem immediately after installation, replacing Hera with Odin on the same computer, the font is just rendered badly.

Cassidy mentioned that they are looking into this.

Comment: Do you have the thread link? I did not find.

Comment: Sorry, I just remember reading it.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same problem.
It seems that replacing Inter font with Ubuntu Regular font make things a little better. Also today there is system update in AppCentre which maybe brings some improvements. Please check it out.

I also tried to find beforementioned discussion on this topic at Reddit. This problem is described in rather long post reviewing cons of eOs - here is the link: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/p7ji4r/eos6_shows_great_promises_but_falls_flat_on_its/